# Java Timer Issues Possibly Involving Storing them in lists

Tags: java, multithreading, list, memory-management

So I will try to discuss the specifics of my program as generally as possible while still getting the general point across. I have two objects of importance, the JobManager, and JobWorkers. A JobWorker has a task it is supposed to execute at fixed intervals until it is completed. I will ignore what happens when the job is completed, because they are never starting. I see the JobManager's timer is being set off, but the JobWorker Timers are not being started. Below is some pseudocode to help you understand the situation.

```
public class JobWorker
{
    private String jobName;
    private Timer timer;
    private Calendar startTime;

    public JobWorker(String jobName, Calendar startTime, otherFields)
    {
        this.jobName = jobName;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.timer = new Timer("EmailJob" + jobName + "-timer");
        //set other fields
    }

    public void start()
    {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

            public void run()
            {
                //Do stuff - this is where nothing is happening
            }

        }, 0, 60000);
    }

    //Equals method and other stuff
}

public class JobManager
{
    private List<JobWorker> activeWorkers = new ArrayList<JobWorker>();
    private List<JobWorker> pausedWorkers = new ArrayList<JobWorker>();

    private Timer timer;

    public JobManager()
    {
        //loads workers from database

        timer = new Timer("JobManager-timer");

        loadJobs();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

            public void run()
            {
                //I see this statement every minute as expected
                logger.info("EmailJobManager timer run started.");

                for(JobWorker worker : pausedWorkers)
                {
                    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();

                    //I can see worker.getStartTime() in client gui so I know that they have already passed
                    if(c.compareTo(worker.getStartTime()) > 0)
                    {
                        //Never see these log statements
                        logger.info("Memory Address in manager timer loop 2 for " + worker.getEmailJobName() + " ({})", worker.toString());

                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy - HH:mm");

                        logger.info("Comparing current time ({}) to JobWorker " + worker.getJobName() + " start time ({})", sdf.format(c.getTime()), sdf.format(worker.getStartDate()));

                        activeWorkers.add(worker);
                        pausedWorkers.remove(worker);
                        worker.start();
                    }
                }
            }

        }, 0, 60000);
    }

    public void addWorker(necessary fields)
    {
        //Create JobWorker newWorker = new JobWorker(jobName, blah blah)
        pausedWorkers.add(newWorker);
    }   

    /**
     * Checks to see if any jobs were not completed as expected due to hardware error. Recreates the EmailJob and EmailJobWorker responsible.
     */
    private void loadJobs()
    {
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM email_jobs";

        List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jt.queryForList(SQL);

        for(Map<String, Object> row : rows)
        {
            JobWorker worker = new JobWorker(stuff it needs from SQL);

            //I see these debug statements
            logger.info("Worker " + worker.getJobName() + " has been added to pausedWorkers list with memory address ({})", worker.toString());
            pausedWorkers.add(worker);

            logger.info("Job " + jobName + " loaded sucessfully.");
        }
}
```

I am going to continue putting some more debug statements in, namely printing out JobWorker memory addresses (Object.toString essentially) to see if there is something weird with deep/shallow copies of them. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Okay, I am at a complete loss for what is happening. So here is the complete class.

http://ideone.com/hR7et

There is nothing sensitive in there so no worries.

Here is the log output I have:

```
2012-04-17 16:34:18,548 INFO [http-bio-8081-exec-97] c.c.e.EmailJobWorker [EmailJobWorker.java:98] EmailJobWorker test was created sucessfully. (batchSize, timeInterval, currentId, startTime) (1, 5, 1, 04/17/12 - 15:15)
2012-04-17 16:34:18,552 INFO [http-bio-8081-exec-97] c.c.e.EmailJobManager [EmailJobManager.java:297] Worker test has been added to pausedWorkers list with memory address (EmailJobWorker@7e7df7d)
2012-04-17 16:34:18,552 INFO [http-bio-8081-exec-97] c.c.e.EmailJobManager [EmailJobManager.java:301] EmailJob test loaded sucessfully.
2012-04-17 16:34:18,557 INFO [http-bio-8081-exec-97] c.c.e.EmailJobWorker [EmailJobWorker.java:98] EmailJobWorker test2 was created sucessfully. (batchSize, timeInterval, currentId, startTime) (1, 5, 1, 04/17/12 - 15:15)
2012-04-17 16:34:18,558 INFO [http-bio-8081-exec-97] c.c.e.EmailJobManager [EmailJobManager.java:297] Worker test2 has been added to pausedWorkers list with memory address (EmailJobWorker@349be26c)
2012-04-17 16:34:18,558 INFO [http-bio-8081-exec-97] c.c.e.EmailJobManager [EmailJobManager.java:301] EmailJob test2 loaded sucessfully.
2012-04-17 16:34:18,558 INFO [http-bio-8081-exec-97] c.c.e.EmailJobManager [EmailJobManager.java:117] EmailJobManager timer started sucesfully. (sleepTime) (1)
2012-04-17 16:34:18,559 INFO [EmailJobManager] c.c.e.EmailJobManager [EmailJobManager.java:74] EmailJobManager timer run started.
2012-04-17 16:34:18,561 INFO [EmailJobManager] c.c.e.EmailJobManager [EmailJobManager.java:85] Size of pausedWorkers: 2
2012-04-17 16:34:18,561 INFO [EmailJobManager] c.c.e.EmailJobManager [EmailJobManager.java:89] Memory Address in manager timer loop 2 for test (EmailJobWorker@7e7df7d)
2012-04-17 16:34:19,501 INFO [EmailJobManager] c.c.e.EmailJobManager [EmailJobManager.java:75] EmailJobManager timer run started.
2012-04-17 16:34:31,984 INFO [EmailJobManager] c.c.e.EmailJobManager [EmailJobManager.java:75] EmailJobManager timer run started.
2012-04-17 16:34:34,562 INFO [EmailJobManager] c.c.e.EmailJobManager [EmailJobManager.java:75] EmailJobManager timer run started.
2012-04-17 16:35:04,840 INFO [EmailJobManager] c.c.e.EmailJobManager [EmailJobManager.java:75] EmailJobManager timer run started.
2012-04-17 16:35:19,501 INFO [EmailJobManager] c.c.e.EmailJobManager [EmailJobManager.java:75] EmailJobManager timer run started.
2012-04-17 16:35:31,984 INFO [EmailJobManager] c.c.e.EmailJobManager [EmailJobManager.java:75] EmailJobManager timer run started.
2012-04-17 16:35:34,562 INFO [EmailJobManager] c.c.e.EmailJobManager [EmailJobManager.java:75] EmailJobManager timer run started.
2012-04-17 16:36:04,840 INFO [EmailJobManager] c.c.e.EmailJobManager
```

As you can see the timer is not even going off every minute, even though EmailJobManager is only created once, and the timers for JobWorkers are never set off.

Comment: If you don't see those log lines, then I don't see what makes you conclude that your problem has to do with anything else than that condition involving `compareTo`.

Comment: I will look into it, as I said I can see what the start times are in my client gui, but perhaps there is some weirdness.

Comment: Save the return value of `compareTo` in a local var and print it out before testing it.

Comment: I posted the actual class, since I just cannot fathom has what my log statements are telling me have anything to do with my logic in if statements and the like.

Comment: Look. Why don't you please write `final int cmp = c.compareTo(worker.getEmailJob().getStartTime()); logger.info("Result of comparison: " + cmp); if (cmp > 0) { ...`

Comment: Because as the logs show, the statements above them are not being set off either, which are basically showing me the comparison. Namely, line 91 should be showing me the result of the comparison, but it is never printed.

Comment: I see. So what you're saying is that line 87 is reached, but line 91 doesn't execute? Then your thread must be getting stuck somewhere in between. Separate out every method call in that section. BTW you are trying to log `worker.getStartDate()` and you are about to test `worker.getEmailJob().getStartTime()`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10202/discussion-between-thatidiotguy-and-marko-topolnik)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I see the JobManager's timer is being set off, but the JobWorker
>   Timers are not being started.

Are you calling `JobWorker.start`? You need to include more code so we can see what's happening. There's no reason those `run` methods shouldn't execute: http://ideone.com/uEer3

Transience is only relevant in serialization.

Comment: I posted some more code to give more of an idea of what is happening, but if you guys are saying that this has nothing to do with how I am storing them in lists, then it must simply be an error with my logic.

Comment: It turns out errors in the run method were not being properly logged. You are absolutely right that there is nothing wrong behind the idea.

Answer (score 0):

So it ended up being errors in my timertasks' run method. Since they are anonymous, the errors did cause interruption of the main method, and failed silently.